# Setting up SPN for SSRS in a CRM load balance environment

Tags: active-directory, iis, kerberos, spn

I'm getting this exception randomly in a CRM load balance LIVE environment when running Reports from CRM.

*System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect*

So my next step is update SPNs for SSRS and CRM domain accounts running its services. In an environment as:

- 2 CRM servers: `live-srv-crm01 ; live-srv-crm02`
- 2 SSRS servers: `live-srv-ssrs01 ; live-srv-ssrs02`

FQDN's servers follow this syntax: `live-srv-crm01.companyname.azure`

I have **NOT** any SPN setup for the domain accounts running Reporting Services service in any of the SRSS servers.

My SPN for the account running CRM App pool are:
`http/live-srv-crm01.companyname.com
http/live-srv-crm01
http/internalcrm.companyname.com
http/internalcrm`

1. Will troubleshoot this setting up SPN for each domain account running Reporting Services service?

`http/live-srv-ssrs01
http/live-srv-ssrs01.companyname.azure`

and

`http/live-srv-ssrs02
http/live-srv-ssrs02.companyname.azure`

2. Or would I need to update SPNs for domain account running CRM app pool?

`http/live-srv-crm-01.companyname.azure
http/live-srv-crm02
http/live-srv-crm02.companyname.azure`

3. To test if executing step 1 works, do I need to `iisreset`?